# how to serialize/deserialize X509Certificate

Tags: java, x509certificate

I see there is code to read one in here

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html

but there is no code for writing one out.

My preference is to write a String and read a String or else I will have to base64 encode.  Anyways, how to serialize it?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Certificates get used as part of the security API, to encrypt transmissions.  It doesn't sound like a good idea to send one to someone else, either over a wire or by writing it to a storage device.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Base64 encoding for certificate is best option, because most major platform support it natively as is.

Comment: @markspace, x509 certificates include only the public key of a key pair, not the private. They can be distributed or stored safely

Comment: Java `String` is defined to handle only characters not binary data, and handling binary data directly as a `String` frequently results in mangling it, which for a certificate (or any other cryptographic object) is fatal. Concur base64 is common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to write a certificate as binary

```
Files.write(
      Paths.get(fileName),
      certificate.getEncoded());
```

And this code will write the certificate to base64

```
 Files.write(
      Paths.get(fileName),
      Base64.getEncoder().encode(certificate.getEncoded()));
```

If you need a PEM file, just add `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` header and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` footer to the base64 file

Java supports reading certificates encoded in PEM or binary format

Comment: For valid PEM **break the base64 into lines of 64 chars** and add the header and trailer. Not all readers enforce the line-length limit but some do. Some other formats, particularly xmldsig&xmlenc, use base64 without linebreaks.

Comment: Since Certificate implements Serializable why not use ObjectOutputStream to serialize and deserialize? If needed, encode the bytes to String using Base64. `ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  try (ObjectOutputStream objStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteStream);) {
   objStream.writeObject(cert);
   objStream.flush();
  }
Base64.getEncoder().encode(byteStream.toByteArray());`

Comment: @stackee007, because ObjectOutputStream result is not standard. PEM or binary DER are standard encodings with built-in support in most programming languages

Comment: I don't think poster didn't ask to store key in a standard format. Though storing in a standard format is recommended, minus the overhead.